# Stop duplicate mails in Django Invoice

Tags: django, python-2.7, invoice

I am using django invoice service for sending mails to customers who are transacted on my app. My code contains this lines.

```
from django.core.mail.message import EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from email.MIMEImage import MIMEImage

def send_mail(html_content):
    email = EmailMultiAlternatives("Invoice Details",text_content,to=[xxxx,xxxx])
    email.attach_alternative(html_content, 'text/html')
    email.send()
```

But whenever I sending mails to customers they receiving 5 to 6 duplicate mails which has same content. How can I stop these duplicate mails in django invoice???

Comment: It is impossible to debug this with this much information. How do you call `send_mail` method? What does your logs say? Are all the emails have the same timestamp etc...

Comment: I am just passing a html rendered variable to send_mail. In logs only one log is logging and all mails containg the same timestimp.

Comment: What Selcuk was asking is to show the code where you call send_mail.